# Fine-tuning SentenceTransformer on text classification task

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, sentence-transformers

Wish to fine-tune SentenceTransformer model with multi-class labeled dataset for text classification.
Tutorials seen so far need a specific format as a training data, such as list of positive triplets such as (senetnce1, sentence2, 1) and list of negative triplets such as (senetnce1, senetnce3, 0).
A typical classification dataset is not like that. Its a list of (senetnce1, class1), (senetnce2, class2), (senetence3, class1), (senetnce4, class3), etc.

Is there any ready logic/code/tutorial which will demonstrate, given a typical classification dataset, generate necessary triplet lists, by permutations and combinations? and then train SentenceTransformer successfully, and hopefully with better accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

If you have small number of samples, ie. for few-shots-training, [SetFit](https://github.com/huggingface/setfit) can be used

If you have large number of samples for fine-tuning, there is unsupervised way called [TSDAE](https://www.sbert.net/examples/unsupervised_learning/TSDAE/README.html).